Inline input field: input 'pushes' the second half of the sentence along
I am building a very simple website where the user enters information 'natively' into input fields in sentences. This means the input field has to act like it's part of the sentence so if the data inputted exceeds the placeholder data, it will push the rest of the sentence along.
Here is an example. Where step 1. there is no interaction. The user then enters 5. When the user enters a second digit, 5 again, it moves ‘minutes’ along.
enter image description here
How can I achieve this?
I have attempted this in a mixture of Webflow and just HTML to try and troubleshoot but to no avail.

Based on how I understand your problem, I use the contenteditable attribute of html and add event listener using javascript:


const editableSentence = document.getElementById('editableSentence');
editableSentence.addEventListener('input', updateSentence);

function updateSentence() {
    const text = editableSentence.innerText;
    const number = text.replace(/\D/g, ''); 
    editableSentence.innerText = number;
}
 #editableSentence:focus-visible{
    outline: none !important; 
 }
<p id="sentence">I have <span id="editableSentence" contenteditable></span> minutes</p>



